# Ansible Automation Platform - Changing 'Control Plane Execution Environment'

Tags: ansible, rhel8, ansible-tower

I have a Ansible Automation Platform 2.1.0 installation on RHEL8.

I have some jobs failing due to an incorrect Registry/image entry for the 'Control Plane Execution Environment'. I am able to replace the incorrect entry in the image field for all of the other Execution Environments (Ansible Engine, Default, etc..) from the GUI.

However, I am unable to modify this field for the 'Control Plane Execution Environment'. I am also unable to delete this execution environment (I attempted to make a Copy, fix the copy, delete the original, and then rename the copy to match). This is the same regardless of the logged in account.

I have done some research, but the only method I have been able to find is to re-install the entire Ansible Automation Platform (as described here: https://www.jazakallah.info/post/how-to-change-control-plane-execution-environment-settings). I also ran `grep -rlw "control_plane_execution_environment" -i /` in an attempt to find any text-based configs that could potentially be modified - but the only files that showed up were part of the installation bundle.

How do I reconfigure or modify the Registry/Image for the Control Plane Execution Environment, preferably without reinstalling the entire Ansible Automation Platform?

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I am using AWX, and not the Automation Controller (aka Ansible Tower) included in the Red Hat Automation Platform, so instructions for the latter might differ.*

This information is stored in the SQL database. I modified it by doing the following (I am using AWX v20.0.0):

- open a shell in the postgresql docker container with `kubectl exec -it <your-postgres-pod> -- bash`
- connect to the `awx` database : `psql -U <your-postgresql-user> -W awx`
- Check the content of the `main_executionenvironment` table and change the EE image in the entry of the Control Plane EE :

  ```
    # Check the content of the table
    SELECT * from main_executionenvironment;

    # Update the entry
    UPDATE main_executionenvironment SET image = '<your-desired-ee-image>' WHERE name='Control Plane Execution Environment';
  ```